# Differentiating under the integral sign and $C^1$ class

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose that $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{R})$ and $g(x)=\int_{0}^{1}f(x+ty)dt$, where $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. How to rigorously show that the function $g(x)$ is continuously differentiable?

Since the function $f(x+ty)$ is continuously differentiable for both $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $t \in ]0,1[$ that result seems very reasonable, but I don't know what is the true mathematical reason behind that result.

Comment: Is this from Tu's manifold ? Seems familiar to me.

Comment: @Sou This question is from random notes but it's clear that this topic pops up here and there in the literature :)

Comment: Well, i'm lucky because you already asked this for me (i dont have a courage to ask this question to be honest). Thanks.

Comment: @Sou I rushed through few sources about differentiating under the integral sign and then I made this "simple" question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}=\int_0^1\frac{f(x+h,ty)-f(x,ty)}{h}\,dt
\to\int_0^1\frac{\partial f(x,ty)}{\partial x}\,dt$$as $h\to0$, because $f\in C^1$ implies the integrand converges uniformly.

Similarly, since $\partial f/\partial x$ is continuous and hence uniformly continuous on compact sets, uniform convergence now shows that $g'$ is continuous.

**Edit:** I've had a request for a reference. In lieu of that, a proof of what's probably the least obvious of the facts used above:

> > If $f\in C^1(\mathbb R)$ then $(f(x+h)-f(x))/h\to f'(x)$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb R$.

Proof: Consider $K=[a,b]$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $f'$ is continuous on $[a-1,b+1]$ it is uniformly continous there; choose $\delta\in(0,1)$ that "witnesses" this uniform  continuity. Now if $x\in[a,b]$ and $0<|h|<\delta$ then MVT shows that $$\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-f'(x)\right|=|f'(\xi)-f'(x)|,$$where $|\xi-x|<\delta$. Hence $\xi\in[a-1,b+1]$ and so $|f'(\xi)-f'(x)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I've been pondering this too. Can you suggest a reference where i can learn these general principle that you use ? (e.g like baby Rudin probably ?).

Comment: Well yes, baby Rudin probably. I'll add a proof of the most important and/or least trivial of the principles I used here - stay tuned.

Comment: Thanks for anwering! I just found this result from **Serge Lang** *Undergraduate analysis* on page 500. That continuity of $g'(x)$ is a trivial addition since the integrand $\partial_x f(x,t)$ is continuous in $x$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : Thank you.